# Suddenly I came to be unable to execute all commands(example:$ ruby -v, $ mysql --version, etc...) at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, macvim

My ruby ​​version is "2.6.6", my mysql version is "5.7", my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I edited `~/.bash_profile` as below and I pushed <kbd>esc</kbd>, `:x`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I executed `source ~/.bash_profile` before suddenly I came to be unable to execute all commands(example:`$ ruby -v`, `$ mysql --version`, etc...) at all.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

Even now, I can't open `~/.bash_profile` ,using this command `vim ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: What does it mean _unable to execute_? You did not post any error message. Also, please do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` and add the version of bash you get to your posting.

Comment: It might be the case that you screwed your $PATH. WHat do you get with `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @user1934428
 When I executed `echo $BASH_VERSION `, `3.2.57(1)-release` was displayed but where should I add this display result? What's my posting? And Where's my posting?

Comment: With _posting_ , I mean to **edit** your question. You have an _Edit_  link below your question. Also don't forget to copy and paste the error messae you get.

Comment: @BroiSatse
When I executed `echo $PATH`, `/Users/MyName/.rbenv/bin:PATH` was displayed.

Comment: As you see, your PATH is nonsense, so I suggest that you fix this first. The problem should be either in .bashrc or in .bash_profile. You can debug this by doing a `/usr/local/bin/bash -lx` and analyze the output.

Comment: @user1934428  When I executed `echo $BASH_VERSION`,  `3.2.57(1)-release` was displayed.  So there isn't the error message.

Comment: Of course not!!! I mean: You  claimed that you are _unable to execute_. In usual case, unless I am unable to execute anything because my computer is physically broken by being dropped on the floor, I get an error message. So the least you can do is to type the command you tried, and then copy and paste the full error message. If you don't get an error message, but, say, the screen suddenly gets dark, you can describe this too.

Comment: Please, do *not* hide important information in the comments. All the relevant information (but *only* the relevant information) *must* be in the question.

Comment: @user1934428 When I executed `/usr/local/bin/bash -lx`, `bash: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory` was displayed. Should I make `/usr/local/bin/bash` directory by using `mkdir` directory? But when I executed `mkdir /usr/local/bin/bash`,  `bash: mkdir: command not found` was displayed. So I can't use `mkdir` directory.

Comment: Note that this is not really a programming question. It is a basic "how do I use a computer" 101 question, and thus more appropriate at [su].

Comment: @Marchan4 : I don't remember exactly, where MacOs puts its standard executables.  If it's not in /usr/local/bin, Just try the usual suspects for locations, i.e. `/usr/bin/bash` or `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**quick fix**

The easiest way to fix this is to just move your ~/.bash_profile out of the way, e.g.

```
/bin/mkdir ~/temp-store-bash-profile
/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/temp-store-bash-profile
```

From there, you can just load up a new terminal, edit your ~/temp-store-bash-profile/.bash_profile file commenting out the offending export line, move it back, and you are good to go.

**Detailed fix**

Of course, unloading your ~/.bash_profile file every time it's messed up is a less than ideal situation. If you'd like to edit it in place, keep reading.

To get you back into vi, the full default path for the pre-installed vim editor is `/usr/bin/vim` . You can use that instead of `vim` as a drop-in replacement. So `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile`

Once you are there you may, in vim,

`:next ~/.bash_profile /etc/paths /etc/paths.d/*`

This will load most if not all of the default PATH sources into your editor. You can go to the next file in the queue with `:next` and the previous file with `:prev` . This will allow you to fully cherry pick what you'd like from your PATH and set up your PATH exactly the way you'd like it.

**When all else fails, make a new user**

An easier method to find out what your default PATH variable is, and sometimes the only way if you've sufficiently messed up your environment (though it is overkill for your situation) is to create a new user profile, then

```
echo "${PATH}" > /tmp/default_path
```

You can do this with any variable you'd like the default for. You will then be able to read this from your profile with a dirty environment.

Comment: I can execute the `cd` command, but I can't execute the `touch` command and the `mkdir` command.

Comment: i just rebooted into macos to check. Use `/bin/mkdir` instead of `mkdir`

Comment: Edited the full commands into my answer

Comment: Generally speaking, you can type out the full path to any command to execute it. `mkdir` checks your PATH variable. `/bin/mkdir` does not.

Comment: I executed `/bin/mkdir ~/temp-store-bash-profile` and `bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/temp-store-bash-profile`. But I can't understand how to load up a new terminal, so would you like to tell me the way?

Comment: `⌘` + `space` to open spotlight, type "Terminal", you should now be able to click `Terminal` to open it

Comment: Another way is to run the command `/bin/bash` from the already open terminal you are typing these commands into. You can test with loading your profile with `/bin/bash --login -i`. To make this easier in the future I highly recommend pinning a shortcut to your Terminal to your Dock at the bottom. This has instructions for that, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3534256 .

Comment: I use the text editor "Atom" so should I type "Atom" in Spotlight Search and click "Atom" after pushing `⌘` + `space`?

Comment: No. One moment I will get a web page with detailed instructions.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/682770/how-to-open-the-terminal-on-a-mac/

Comment: For fixing the error that I can't execute all commands(example:`$ ruby -v`, `$ mysql --version`, etc...) at all, I executed `/bin/mkdir ~/temp-store-bash-profile` and `/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/temp-store-bash-profile`  and then type "Atom" in Sportlight Search and click "Atom" and open "Atom" and I was able to execute the commands(example:`$heroku open`, `$rails s`).  I was able to resolve this error thanks to you. Thank you very much for politely answering my question.

Comment: I was happy to help. In the future please ask this kind of question in the Super User stack overflow site, https://superuser.com/